# 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'texture' and no accessible extension method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

> "Image" does not contain a definition for "texture" and no accessible extension method "texture" accepting a first argument of type "Image" could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CFX_Demo_GTToggle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture Normal;

    public Texture Hover;

    public Color NormalColor = new Color32(128, 128, 128, 128);

    public Color DisabledColor = new Color32(128, 128, 128, 48);

    public bool State = true;

    public string Callback;

    public GameObject Receiver;

    private Rect CollisionRect;

    private bool Over;

    private Image Label;

    private void Awake()
    {
        CollisionRect = GetComponent<Rect>().GetScreenRect(Camera.main);
        Label = GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        UpdateTexture();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (CollisionRect.Contains(Input.mousePosition))
        {
            Over = true;
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                OnClick();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Over = false;
            GetComponent< Image>().color = NormalColor;
        }
        UpdateTexture();
    }

    private void OnClick()
    {
        State = !State;
        Receiver.SendMessage(Callback);
    }

    private void UpdateTexture()
    {
        Color color = (!State) ? DisabledColor : NormalColor;
        if (Over)
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().texture = Hover;
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().texture = Normal;
        }
        GetComponent<Image>().color = color;
        if (Label != null)
        {
            Label.color = color * 1.75f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is in the C# programming language, not the UnityScript language, so I've removed the UnityScript tag for you.

Comment: Well the error is correct there is no texture for image

Comment: Yes, of course the [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Image.html) type does not declare a `texture` property/field. The error message you got pretty much says as much. (See for yourself in the official documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Image.html. Official documentations rather often are actually worth looking up, btw). Thanks for letting us know anyways...

Comment: so now what i do can anyone tell me please

Comment: Use 'Sprite' type instead of 'Texture' in field declaration for Normal and Hover and assign them to Image.sprite

Answer (score 0):

given that the project is 'CFX_Demo_GTToggle' script from fx pack

```
CollisionRect = this.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image>().GetPixelAdjustedRect();
```

The answer you needed:

```
this.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create((Texture2D)Hover, new Rect(0, 0, Hover.width, Hover.height), 0.5f * Vector2.one);
```